# Conditional display of p:overlayPanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I show/hide the overlay panel conditionally from @ManagedBean based on some result.
In the below code: `p:overlayPanel` is for `p:commandButton`. I want to show overlay panel conditionally from Action method.
Right now it is showing every time I click the commandbutton.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:outputLabel value="Town Name:"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.town}"/>
    <p:commandButton id="checkBtn" value="Check" action="#{myBean.action}"/>

    <p:overlayPanel  widgetVar="overL" id="over" for="checkBtn">
       <h:outputText value="This town is not Listed in our records"/>
    </p:overlayPanel>
</h:form>
```

**Note** : I'm using *****Primefaces 3.5*****

Answer (score 0):

Give the overlay panel a widget name and set showEvent to none (this kills the default behavior and assign a javascript handle to the panel):

```
widgetVar="myOverlay" showEvent="none"
```

add oncomplete attr to you button, something like:

```
oncomplete="if(args && !args.validationFailed) myOverlay.show();"
```

Comment: had the same issue, adding widgetVar worked for me but I had to do `PF('myOverlay').show();`