# PrimeFaces - weird event handlers after added overlaypanel to inputText

Tags: primefaces, preventdefault

I have form with input field:

```
<p:inputText id="M25BRAN" value="#{bean.value}" />
```

When user press "ENTER" form is submitted.

But after I added overlay panel (it is shown programmatically by a JS script function - onmousemove):

```
<p:overlayPanel id="M25BRAN_overlaypanel" widgetVar="M25BRAN_overlay_panel" for="M25BRAN" showEvent="null" hideEvent="null">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.memoText}" />
</p:overlayPanel>
```

When user press "ENTER", the small and empty overlaypanel is shown (small white rectangle). I am suspecting that this is the reason (red border):

http://s1.postimg.org/6u1mtn9fz/ovp.png

But I don't know why PF bunds this additional event handlers (onkey up/down). They are present only if overlaypanel is bound to component. How can I disable this additional events?

Comment: 'null' as events is weird…  but I might be wrong. If it is something that is?explicitly supported by PF, please post a reference to the docs

Comment: I have tried also with "none" event (based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/19665668/4745335) - the same effect.